# Handle one time event on Redux - animation after action

Tags: redux

Let's say after an action `BUTTON_CLICKED`, all I need to do is show some animation and go back to the way it was before (ex.: a circle expands and goes back to original size).

How do I handle that in terms of state?

I could have `shouldAnimate = true` then the UI does the animation and sends an action to set it back to `shouldAnimate = false`, but that seems weird, since that second action would not really do anything, it would just change the `shouldAnimate` state to make sure that the next time something else changes in the state tree, the animation doesn't happen again.

**Adding a specific example:**

When a button is clicked, we should change the color of a circle from red to green or from green to red. So it's just a toggle button. If we are changing from green to red and if a boolean value from the server is true, we do an animation expanding the circle and going back to the original size.

```
func buttonColorReducer(buttonColor: String, action: Action) {
    switch action {
    case let action as ToggleButtonAction:
        return buttonColor == "Red" ? "Green" : "Red"
    default:
        return buttonColor
    }
}

func toggleButtonActionCreator() {
    dispatch(ToggleButtonAction)

    fetchCanAnimateFromServer(callback: { canAnimate in
        if store.state.buttonColor == "Red" && canAnimate {
            // do animation
        }
    })
}

func buttonClicked() {
    toggleButtonActionCreator()
}
```

Comment: Why use redux for this at all? Is there any reason the state actually needs to know about the animation? is the animation css? if it's just a single click you could just have a click listener and fire than animation internally in the component.

Comment: I'm developing on iOS with Swift. Yes, there is a reason =), but I'd have to go into a lot more detail to explain. But basically, I need to fire the animation due to an action (that will also do more stuff). The animation happens maybe after the action has been processed, so I can't just start it in the component. Also, the animation might happen conditionally, based on how the action is processed.

Comment: Does the animation have a promise or callback you can use? Or is it a function you can call? What is the animation itself? You probably don't wan to flag a bool like you are suggestion (if you can get away with it).

Comment: In some cases I do have a callback, in some cases I don't (stupid framework design...), but let's assume I do have a callback in the animation, still, how/where do I trigger it?

Comment: If you do you'd use it in the action creators. Assuming you're you have dispatch in your action creators - you can chain actions synchronously with a promise or callback

Comment: I'm not sure I follow: 1) component calls action creator; 2) action creator dispatches action; 3) reducers update state; 4) same action creator checks the resulting state to see if it needs animation?; 5) action creator calls the component to trigger the animation?

Comment: The action doesn't happen after the animation, it's the other way around.

Comment: Yes I know that's why you want a callback or whatever - pass that to action, fire animation, on complete of animation do additional logic then rest of action. Just reverse that if its opposit of what I'm saying, you are not limited to firing 1 action in the action creators, you can set up callbacks or promises that fire multiple

Comment: You mean pass a callback, containing the animation code, to the action creator? That seems very weird, since now I'm coupling the action creator with component specifics and not through the state tree. Could you present an answer with a small code example of what you mean?

Comment: It's kind of hard you are providing a lot of unknowns, like how the animation works and are you expecting it to fire after the state has changed? Can you go into detail about that a bit more?

Comment: @ajmajmajma I added a specific example to my question.

Comment: I don't mean to be pedantic, but that example is still not very specific. The server call you are talking about here that has the boolean value - where is this happening and when? Is it when you click the button and the animation is fired afterwards? Is the call even relevant to the button click? Is it done before all of this and already on the state? Break your problem down into a few steps and it will be much easier to help. Toggling the button back and forth via a bool is easy, but how does that server call play into this?

Comment: No problem, I updated my question with some code, that might be clearer. But in any case, the server call happens in the action creator. Yes, the animation happens after clicking the button. It is relevant to determine if we will trigger an animation or not.